# URLDecoder.decode(encodedString, "UTF-8") alternative

Tags: java

URLDecoder.decode throws `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Is there any other way to achieve decoding, without handling this exception?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String encodedString = "Testing some character I want to claim %C2%A3300.00 I want to claim %24400.00 I want to claim %E2%82%AC500.00";
    System.out.println( URLDecoder.decode(encodedString, "UTF-8"));
    byte[] bytes = encodedString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String s2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(s2); //doesnt work
    String decoded = new String(encodedString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    System.out.println(decoded); //doesnt work
}
```

Output:

```
Testing some character I want to claim £300.00 I want to claim $400.00 I want to claim €500.00
Testing some character I want to claim %C2%A3300.00 I want to claim %24400.00 I want to claim %E2%82%AC500.00
Testing some character I want to claim %C2%A3300.00 I want to claim %24400.00 I want to claim %E2%82%AC500.00
```

Comment: why exactly do you expect that casting bytes of the **encoded** string to a new string decodes it? and no there is no way to do it without handling the exception

Comment: Your first line claims that `URLDecoder.decode` throws `UnsupportedEncodingException` - but then you've provided code and output suggesting it doesn't. Which is it?

Comment: URLDecoder.decode(encodedString, "UTF-8") - this one works with the exception.

Comment: the other 2 - encodedString.getBytes("UTF-8") , encodedString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") doesnt work.

Comment: i want an alternate to achieve decoding , instead of using URLDecoder.decode

Comment: Charset encoding is different from URL encoding.  `new String` and `getBytes()` do not perform URL encoding.

Comment: What do you mean by "works with the exception"? Does it work, or does it throw an exception? Those are mutually exclusive. It's really, really unclear what you're actually trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache commons [URLCodec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec.html#decode(java.lang.String)):

```
String decoded = new URLCodec().decode(encodedString);
```

According to the docs:

> This codec is meant to be a replacement for standard Java classes URLEncoder and URLDecoder on older Java platforms, as these classes in Java versions below 1.4 rely on the platform's default charset encoding.

You still have to handle the `DecoderException` though.